# Struts2 JSP throws a NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am doing a project in `Struts 2`, but when I run a simple `JSP` page, I got this error stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:      
        com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/ContainerProvider
    and also org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
        javax.servlet.ServletException: 
            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
                com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/ContainerProvider    
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)     
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)   
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)                
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)            
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: This Error is also coming  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!The    Struts dispatcher cannot be found. This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag.

Comment: That error is because you're hitting a JSP page directly instead of running through an action. Hitting JSP pages in S2 is almost always an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `xwork-core` library. Put the proper version (depends on the exact version of Struts you use - see Struts documentation) into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your web application. If you use Maven to build your project, add proper dependency to your `pom.xml` file.

Comment: I use Netbeans to build our project